# What does it mean to vanish at infinity faster than any power of $|x|$?

Tags: real-analysis

The Schwartz space is informally defined as the space of $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ functions which, together with their derivatives, vanish at infinity faster than any power of $|x|$.  I find this strange because no non-negative power of $|x|$ vanishes at infinity.  The explicit definition is 
$$\mathcal{S} = \{f \in \mathcal{C}^\infty : \sup_{x \in \Bbb R^n} (1+|x|)^N |\partial^\alpha f(x)| < \infty \text{ for all } N \in \Bbb N \text{ and all } \alpha \in \Bbb N^{n}\}.$$ Can someone please explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that any power of $|x|$ will not grow fast enough when going to infinity to "counter" the speed at which $f$ and his derivatives vanish.

So when you multiply $f \in \mathcal{S}$ or one of his derivatives by $|x|^N$ for any $N \in \mathbb{N}$, the limit will be $0$ when $|x|$ goes to infinity.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  And it seems like a really strong condition.  But I can easily see from this explanation why, say, the $\mathcal{C}^\infty_c$ functions are contained in $\mathcal{S}$.  Thanks very much.  In the norm on $\mathcal{S}$, do you know why we multiply by $(1+|x|)^N$ instead of $|x|^N$?

Comment: Indeed, $|x|^N$ is enough. But sometimes we use $(1+|x|)^N$ because we define an other space with it made of functions who increase at polynomial speed. (I don't know the english term for it sorry) So this is used to emphasize the fact that any function in $\mathcal{S}$ is stable by multiplication with the "polynomial" ones. (and also that any function in $\mathcal{S}$ vanishes faster than them)

Comment: I see that when we expand $(1+|x|)^N$, we arrive at an expression involving terms of the form $|x|^n$ for every $n$ between $0$ and $N$, so I would say your explanation makes sense.